# etcd-wrapper | etcdmain: rejected connection from "" (tls: "" does not match any of DNSNames [""])

Tags: coreos, etcd

I create a etcd cluster, after the upgrade I start seeing the following error:

```
etcd-wrapper[11905]| etcdmain: rejected connection from "" (tls: "" does not match any of DNSNames [""])
```

I am not sure what its means? I provide the certificate with DNS names which is not working currently, and an ip address. I see the requests are coming from the right IP address, but they are being rejected. It was working previous not sure what changed.

Do I remove those DNS entries and its will resolve the issue?

Is there a way to bypass it from a parameter in etcd?

Comment: I have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494288/install-kubernetes-cilium-on-different-networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out the certs generated had the wrong DNS names that were not used, and just generated new certs removing the unneeded DNS information and resolved the DNSNames rejected issue.

The TLS issue is due to mis-configuration of config, I miss configured some parameters with HTTP instead of HTTPS. Please make sure all the configuration is HTTPS or else its will throw this error and other errors.