# Install Kubernetes + Cilium on different networks

Tags: networking, kubernetes, installation

There is the following topology:

[image]

'left-1', 'left-2', 'right-1', 'right-2', 'center' - hosts (DNS names are same).

"Clouds" - networks.

kubeadm, kubectl, kubelet, docker on all hosts installed correctly.

Kubernetes need install like: 'Master-1' on host 'left-1', 'Master-2' on host 'right-1', and workers on hosts 'left-2' and 'right-2'

All hosts ping each other by the domain name. All ports on all hosts are open. No firewall anywhere.

All hosts have access to the internet.

Here there is a manual to install Kubernetes:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

If I install Kubernetes only on 'left-1' and 'left-2' - all works fine.

If I install Kubernetes only on 'right-1' and 'right-2' - all works fine.

But if I install on all nodes - pods from the left do not connect to pods from right, and right pods do not connect to left pods.

How to install Kubernetes on the left and right nodes together?

I use a Cilium network.

I installed a Cilium network with the command:

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cilium/cilium/v1.6.8/install/kubernetes/quick-install.yaml

When i init the first master node, i describe CIDR: 10.217.0.0/16

I tried to install etcd separately from kubernetes. i've got error:

`2020-06-25 02:49:37.073290 I | embed: rejected connection from "10.7.0.1:48422" (error "tls: \"10.7.0.1\" does not match any of DNSNames [\"right-1\" \"localhost\"]", ServerName "", IPAddresses ["10.8.1.1" "127.0.0.1" "::1" "10.8.1.1"], DNSNames ["right-1" "localhost"])`

10.7.0.1 - it is `center`, and center is not a part of the etcd cluster. Why etcd checks it?

```
[left-1]$ traceroute right-1
traceroute to right-1 (10.8.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  center (10.7.0.1)  1.381 ms  1.252 ms  1.159 ms
 2  right-1 (10.8.1.1)  1.068 ms  0.990 ms  0.912 ms
```

Comment: Can you post what you used for your Cillium installation?

Comment: I install Cilium with the command:

   kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cilium/cilium/v1.6.8/install/kubernetes/quick-install.yaml

Comment: Is Cilium running on all your Kubernetes nodes when you are using the nodes on the left and right?  That's basically your overlay.

Comment: cilium/operator - runs on one node, cilium/cilium runs on all nodes (DaemonSet)

Comment: I forget: i described CIDR: 10.217.0.0/16 when init the first master node

Comment: Please tell me, does anyone have working kubernetes on such topology? I am desperate!

Comment: See if there's a difference between the pod IP addresses running in west and east? is it a different subnet?  It could be a network policy that it's preventing them to communicate with each other.

Comment: Command:

`kubectl exec -it pod-on-left-1 -- ifconfig`

Shows:

`eth0 ... inet addr:10.217.3.200 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Mask:255.255.255.255`

Command:

`kubectl exec -it pod-on-right-1 -- ifconfig`

Shows:

`eth0 ... inet addr:10.217.0.130 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Mask:255.255.255.255`

Comment: What is command to see is network policy preventing communication or not?

Comment: We try to use kube-router instead Cilium. And network does not work too.

Comment: `kubectl get netpol` for network policies

Comment: you just have some sort of firewalll between left and right preventing traffic

Comment: Command `kubectl get netpol --all-namespaces` says: `No resources found`

Comment: "some sort of firewalll between left and right preventing traffic" - it was our the first mind - we check it at the first place - all firewalls downed. We used `netcat` for different ports (6443, 10250, 10251, 10252, 2379-2380, etc) like `nc -l 10251` and then connect `nc IP 10251` - all ok. From left to right hosts. BUT. When install kubernetes then pods cannot connect from left to right.

Comment: We see port list here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Comment: How do you test connection between pods? Are there any errors?

Comment: The first: i see IP: `kubeadm exec -it some-left-pod -- ifconfig`. Then i run command: `kubeadm exec -it some-left-pod -- nc -l -p 7001`. Open another terminal and run command: `kubeadm exec -it some-RIGHT-pod -- nc  ${IP}  7001`. It must create one way chat. If chat OK, then connection OK. Otherwise - connection NOT ok.

Comment: If not ok - no any errors happened. If wait - timeout errors. The feeling that network packets are disappearing. Like DROP in IPTABLES

Comment: I tried to install etcd separately from kubernetes. i've got error:

`2020-06-25 02:49:37.073290 I | embed: rejected connection from "10.7.0.1:48422" (error "tls: \"10.7.0.1\" does not match any of DNSNames [\"right-1\" \"localhost\"]", ServerName "", IPAddresses ["10.8.1.1" "127.0.0.1" "::1" "10.8.1.1"], DNSNames ["right-1" "localhost"])`

10.7.0.1 - it is `center`, and center is not a part of the etcd cluster. Why etcd checks it?

Answer (score 1):

We solved the problem.

Cluster must be created by command:

`kubeadm init --config=kubeadm-config.yaml --upload-certs`

Where kubeadm-config.yaml contains:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: 1.18.3
controlPlaneEndpoint: "10.7.1.1:6443"
networking:
  podSubnet: "10.217.0.0/16"
etcd:
  local:
    serverCertSANs: ["10.7.1.1", "10.7.2.2", "10.7.0.1", "10.8.1.1", "10.8.2.2", "10.8.0.1"]
    peerCertSANs:   ["10.7.1.1", "10.7.2.2", "10.7.0.1", "10.8.1.1", "10.8.2.2", "10.8.0.1"]
```

Pay attention to yaml-parameters: serverCertSANs, and peerCertSANs : its contain `10.7.0.1` and `10.8.0.1` - these IPs come to node in network packages as client IP and must be registered as trusted IP. If you have another IPs in inter-node interaction, it must be registered too.